# Is it possible to create a new ejs file based on the previous file?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I am trying to create a navbar for my site, and I wonder how to have ejs files automatically have code added from another ejs file. In flask in python it is done on the `{% block title%}` principle and in another file it is done `{% extends 'base.html'%}` and then `{% block title%} This is title {% endblock%}` 
Does anyone know if this is possible in javascript? 
I am using javascript express and the ejs rendering engine.

Comment: are you looking for ejs includes? https://ejs.co/#docs look for includes section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use include statement, see https://ejs.co/#docs the "includes" part.

You can include (as if import) an ejs template with

```
<%- include('mifile', {mykey: mydata, mykey2: myotherdata}); %>
```

The only thing i don't like its the passing parameters explicitly from one template to another, that can be made many times at many levels (an include inside an included template).

I don't know if is there a base/parent template thing like in jinja2 (inheritance), I think not.

Comment: then how do others make navbar and foother always on their site?